# how to get the result from a sub activity

Tags: android

When user presses a button from a webview, I open a scrollview activity with some buttons and edittext fields.

Once the user enters the fields and presses the 'create' button, from scrollview activity, I want the results from the called activity to be accessible.

How can I do thi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you call [setResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int)) on the activity

I've done something like this:

```
private void executeDone() {
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
    resultIntent.putExtra("value", TextEntryActivity.this.et.getText().toString());
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
    finish();
}
```

In the calling Activity:

```
public void launchPreferedNameEdit() {
    Intent foo = new Intent(this, TextEntryActivity.class);
    foo.putExtra("value", objItem.getPreferedNickname());
    this.startActivityForResult(foo, EDIT_PREFERED_NAME);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case EDIT_PREFERED_NAME:
            try {
                String value = data.getStringExtra("value");
                if (value != null && value.length() > 0) {
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: k!
but how do I receive the "value" variable in the called activity? 
There should be something like getResult();

Comment: you launch the activity with `startActivityForResult` and you override the `onActivityResult` where you get the result